# BigCouch all_nodes vs cluster_nodes

Tags: couchdb

I have a BigCouch cluster that I'm spinning up in EC2. I've launched the instances correctly and set the proper constants, but when I try to let the nodes know about each other, their "_membership" lists all the nodes I've added in "cluster_nodes" but not in "all_nodes". Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I just heard from Robert Newson on IRC that BigCouch nodes are connected lazily.